# How do you transition back and forth between dae scenes?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

Here is a slightly modified starter SceneKit project--I added another .dae file named planet.dae. Tap the "ship" to switch to planet.dae. Tap the planet to switch back to ship.dae. Tapping ship does open planet.dae. But when user taps the planet, nothing happens--doesn't seem to recognize my touch.  What gives?

```
 import SceneKit
 class GameViewController: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()
    shipScene()
}

func shipScene() {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.dae")!
    let ship = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("ship", recursively: true)!
    let scnView = self.view as SCNView
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleShipTap:")
    let gestureRecognizers = NSMutableArray()
    gestureRecognizers.addObject(tapGesture)
    if let existingGestureRecognizers = scnView.gestureRecognizers {
        gestureRecognizers.addObjectsFromArray(existingGestureRecognizers)
    }
    scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers
}

func handleShipTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let scnView = self.view as SCNView
    let p = gestureRecognize.locationInView(scnView)
    if let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: nil) {
        if hitResults.count > 0 {
            let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]

            if result.node!.name!.hasPrefix("ship") {
                planetScene()
            }
        }
    }
}
func planetScene() {
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/saturn.dae")!
    let ship = scene.rootNode.childNodeWithName("planet", recursively: true)!
    let scnView = self.view as SCNView
    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePlanetTap:")
    let gestureRecognizers = NSMutableArray()
    gestureRecognizers.addObject(tapGesture)
    if let existingGestureRecognizers = scnView.gestureRecognizers {
        gestureRecognizers.addObjectsFromArray(existingGestureRecognizers)
    }
    scnView.gestureRecognizers = gestureRecognizers
}

func handlePlanetTap(gestureRecognize: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let scnView = self.view as SCNView
    let p = gestureRecognize.locationInView(scnView)
    if let hitResults = scnView.hitTest(p, options: nil) {
        if hitResults.count > 0 {
            let result: AnyObject! = hitResults[0]

            if result.node!.name!.hasPrefix("saturn") {
                shipScene()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is your "saturn" node holding the geometry? What is `result` equal to?

Comment: Hi mnuages! Yes, "saturn" node does include all the geometry used to make the saturn object. I have accepted that there can only be one SCNScene. And we are allowed to add and remove nodes to the one scene. Or, can there be more than one scene and user can tap a node in one scene to flip to another scene and visa versa.

Comment: the issue might be that you'll end up with several tap gesture recognizers (`gestureRecognizers.addObjectsFromArray(existingGestureRecognizers)`). When you load the planet scene, it's still possible that it is the first recognizer that will be triggered (and thus build the planet scene again)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the tapGesture from the planetScene() is all.